# updateSelectinput throws a session not found error

Tags: r, shiny

I am using this code, and keep running into a Error in updateSelectInput: object 'session' not found. This happens when I try to upload any file, through the fileInput option. When I remove the updateSelectInput statement, the table prints fine. (Note that Im providing the bare minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem, the code doesnt include portions where I expect to use the SelectInput inputs).

```
library(shiny); library(shinythemes); library(DT)

ui<- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "default_csv",label="input the file"),
      selectInput(inputId = "facility_id1", label="Choose the facilityID column", choices ="FacilityID"),
      numericInput(inputId = "obs", label="Choose number of obs", value=10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)



server<- function(input, output){

  data_set <- reactive({
    data_set<-read.csv(input$default_csv$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
  observe({
    req(input$default_csv)
    dsnames <- names(data_set())

    updateSelectInput(session, "facility_id1", label = "Facility ID", 
                      choices = dsnames, selected = "")

    cat("update done")
  })
  output$table<- renderDataTable(head(data_set(),n=input$obs))
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)

Warning: Error in updateSelectInput: object 'session' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    57: updateSelectInput
    56: observerFunc [C:/Users//Desktop/9.R#29]
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The server function is missing the `session` argument:

```
server <- function(input, output, session)
```

Comment: Slaps forehead.

Comment: I was positive it wasn't, and indeed it was.

Comment: I am facing this exact same issue however this solution is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Incase your code contains input elements , you may try this:

```
server <- function(input, output,session){

   options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10*1024^2) 

     data_input <- reactive({
     req(input$csv_input)
     fread(input$csv_input$datapath)
  })

   observeEvent(data_input(),{
   choices <- c(not_sel,names(data_input()))
   updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
   updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
   updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "fact_var", choices = choices)
  })
```